# Not able to load the data in JavaRDD<Row>

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am very new to spark

i could see the data using **loadrisk.show()** method but when I am creating the object **JavaRDD balRDD = loadrisk.javaRDD();** I am getting null pointer.

```
public class LoadBalRDD implements Serializable {   

  public JavaPairRDD getBalRDD(SQLContext sqlContext) {

    Dataset<Row> loadrisk = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true")
            .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("/home/data/test.csv");

    loadrisk.show(); // able to see the result 

    JavaRDD<Row> balRDD = loadrisk.javaRDD(); // here not loading 
    JavaPairRDD<String, Balrdd> balRDDMap = balRDD.mapToPair(x -> {

        String aml_acc_id = "";
        if (!x.isNullAt(x.fieldIndex("aml_acc_id")))
            aml_acc_id = x.getAs("aml_acc_id").toString();

        Tuple2<String, Balrdd> tp = new Tuple2(x.getAs(x.fieldIndex("aml_acc_id")).toString(),
                new Balrdd(aml_acc_id));
        return tp;
    }).repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new CustomAcctIdPartitioner());
    return balRDDMap;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you're new to Spark, is there a reason you're not using SparkSession rather than SQLContext?

Comment: I've CSV which will have one column as a primary key and I've more then 20 CSV file. now i have to join all the 20 csv and create 1 csv based on primary key and after that i've to store in hive. i am using spark 1.6

Comment: You could join them in Hive rather than all in memory with Spark. In any case, please show us the stacktrace of the error. Also, if all your files have the same schema, and placed within, `/home/data/`, then spark can read them all at once into a single Dataset, you don't need to read one file at a time